# Filtering data in R with same ID and determining rows which are in both data frames and which rows are not in both data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

Does anyone know another method for filtering data when there is twice the same ID (Column X) in a data frame but with a different associate value (columns Y)?

Basically I wan to know which rows are in both data frame and after I want to know which row is not in both data frame (Actually I want the value of X and Y of this particular row)

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
   > x <- seq(1:10)
    > x[5] <- 4
    > y <- (seq.int(1,19,2))
    > 
    > x<- cbind(x,y)
    > x
           x  y
     [1,]  1  1
     [2,]  2  3
     [3,]  3  5
     [4,]  4  7
     [5,]  4  9
     [6,]  6 11
     [7,]  7 13
     [8,]  8 15
     [9,]  9 17
    [10,] 10 19
    > 
    > z <- x[1:4,]
    > y <- x[6:10,]
    > 
    > z <- rbind(z,y)
    > z
           x  y
     [1,]  1  1
     [2,]  2  3
     [3,]  3  5
     [4,]  4  7
     [5,]  6 11
     [6,]  7 13
     [7,]  8 15
     [8,]  9 17
     [9,] 10 19
    > 
    > df1 <- z[z[,1] %in% x[,1]] 
    > 
    > matrix(df1,9,2) # As expected I'm getting 9 rows
          [,1] [,2]
     [1,]    1    1
     [2,]    2    3
     [3,]    3    5
     [4,]    4    7
     [5,]    6   11
     [6,]    7   13
     [7,]    8   15
     [8,]    9   17
     [9,]   10   19
    > 
    > # Now I want to know what is the value inside the missing row
    > df2 <- z[!z[,1] %in% x[,1]] 
    > 
    > matrix(df2,1,2) # I'm getting NA and NA, bu I was expecting the values 4 and 9
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]   NA   NA
```

Comment: You have duplicated row in z , and all item contain in x , what is your expected output

Comment: My expected output when I do z[!z[,1] %in% x[,1]]  is the row #5 in x (4 and 9)

Comment: Yep , i notice that and provide an answer.

Comment: Your question is asking two fairly different things: 1) filtering data when there is twice the same ID, and 2) rows are in both data frame and after I want to know which row is not in both data frame.

Comment: @AidanGawronski Thank I updated the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use @hansjaneinvielleicht method:

```
xlist <- paste(x[,1], x[,2])
zlist <- paste(z[,1], z[,2])

setdiff(xlist, zlist)
# [1] "4 9"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is to filter for values that are not present in `x[,1]`. However, since 4 is in there, it's also filtered out.

Instead, I assume you'd probably want to work with setdiff method from dplyr ([see the doc here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/setops.html))

Then use `df2 <- setdiff(x, z)`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the cumcount here to adding another key for distinguish the duplicate value in `x[,1]`

```
v=ave(x[,1]==x[,1], x[,1], FUN=cumsum)
t=ave(z[,1]==z[,1], z[,1], FUN=cumsum)
df2 <- x[!paste(x[,1],v) %in% paste(z[,1],t)]
matrix(df2,1,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- data.frame(x)
z <- data.frame(z)
x$from <- "x"
z$from <- "z"

df2 <- merge(x, z, by = c("x", "y"), all.x = T)
df2
# x  y from.x from.y
# 1   1  1      x      z
# 2   2  3      x      z
# 3   3  5      x      z
# 4   4  7      x      z
# 5   4  9      x   <NA>
# 6   6 11      x      z
# 7   7 13      x      z
# 8   8 15      x      z
# 9   9 17      x      z
# 10 10 19      x      z

df2 <- df2[is.na(df2$from.y),]
df2
# x y from.x from.y
# 5 4 9      x   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my real problem was not the one posted since it was too complicated.

Basically, I was not able to apply any solution to my real problem since my real data frames were containing all data types and had a lot of columns.

But I was able to found a solution than work for my real problem but also for the problem posted in the question, so I post the answer than solved my real problem in case it can be useful for someone!

```
> dup <- which(duplicated(x[,1]) == TRUE)
> ans <- matrix(x[dup,],1,2)
> ans
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    9

> # I'm doing this in case the answer was not NA in df2 at the previous step, without
  # providing the row "missing"
> df2 <- rbind(df2, ans)
> df2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    9
```